# Play a video using pure actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

Creating an empty movie clip and attaching it to the stage, I want
to play an flv using only actionscript 2 .. I hear audio, but no video.

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.filters.*;
import flash.geom.*;
import flash.net.*;
import mx.utils.*;
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;


_root.createEmptyMovieClip("vidsurface",_root.getNextHighestDepth());
vidsurface.beginFill(0x000000, 100);
vidsurface.moveTo(0, 0);
vidsurface.lineTo(100, 0);
vidsurface.lineTo(100, 100);
vidsurface.lineTo(0,100);
vidsurface.lineTo(0,0);
vidsurface._visible=true;


var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);
var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
vidsurface.attachVideo(ns);
ns.play("http://nicolasguy.free.fr/flv/cpe.flv");


ns.onStatus = function(info:Object)
{
    trace("NetStream.onStatus called: ("+getTimer()+" ms)"+"  "+info.code);
}
```

Comment: Do you get any traces from your ns.onStatus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a long time since I did AS2, what you need to do is create a video object in the library in IDE. Which type you use depends on which IDE you have, it used to be just a video instance, then I think we got MediaDisplay and then FLVPlayback. Check the components panel to see which instances are available to you.

Give the video object an instance name and use that name to attach your netStream to.

eg:

```
myVideo.attachVideo(ns);
```

Then you will see the video.

Comment: Thanks.. I just read up, that AS2 allows video objects to be created dynamically, and the code looks a lot simpler than AS2.. - I guess, I'm going with AS3 ..

Comment: @Ashod Apakian - AS3 definately the way to go - glad you got sorted